Does BigQuery have a way to convert "Select * " to "Select col1, col2, col3..."
When using Azure Data Studio, I can use ctrl + space after "Select t.* " and it will populate all of the column names into my select statement. Is there an equivalent function in BigQuery?
Tried various combinations of ctrl, alt, command (Mac) but no luck.

My belief is that there is no hot key combination.  For me, when I want to add column names into the query, I use BigQuery studio, look at the schema and then click on the column names I want to use in the schema view.  These are then inserted into the SQL editor at the current cursor position.


I didn't know about that feature, and it's definitely useful. Thanks for enlightening me on it.
